# Themes not working properly in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

Some themes don't seem to be working properly on my fresh install of Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.

I've tried a number of GTK themes (using the Tweak Tool).

Specifically, I've tried the United themes (all three), and POP! But they all have the same issue. The top bar is very small, lacks detail and just generally looks wrong (see screen shots). Numix and Adwaita, which came pre installed, look fine.

How POP theme looks on my desktop:
[image]

How POP should look:
[image]

How United theme looks on my desktop:
[image]

How Numix looks (I think it's how it's supposed to look):
[image]

I've tried researching the issue but nothing is coming up...

Does anyone know what might be causing it? Any way I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To select your theme you to change all applicable appearance options in the **Tweak** tool. Select your theme Properties:

1. GTK+: **Theme Name**
2. Icons: **Icon Pack**
3. Cursor: **Cursor Theme**
4. Shell Theme: **Theme Name**

Selecting the theme alone will not effect the other changes for you. This gives you the flexibility to mix up theme, icons and cursors to your liking.